# Master Equation

Tags: quantum-mechanics, hilbert-space, quantum-information, density-operator

Could anybody help me to understand the master equation in quantum optics, how the master equation describe the motion of quantum state that interact with environment. And how to relate it with Kraus operator representation?

Comment: Do you specifically want to know why the Lindblad operator has a particular form? or why do you need to add it to account for the environment?

Comment: Yes sir. I want to understand how the master equation describe the interaction with environment,  yes why Lindblad operator.

Answer (score 1):

You can surely find original work of the Goran Lindblad about it. For the system weakly  interacting with reservoir, there is Bloch Redfield master equation

\begin{equation}
\frac{d}{dt}\rho_{S}(t)=-\int^{\infty}_{0}ds tr_{\epsilon} \left\lbrace [H_{I}(t),[H_{I}(t-s),\rho_{s}(t)\otimes\rho_{\epsilon}]] \right\rbrace 
\end{equation}

in the case of markovian process.